# function returns undefined, should return promise or value

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting value inside token variable but the code is producing error saying that function should return promise or value. the reason for which I would like to access token is to send notification to the receiver about the received request. my problematic code snippet is present below.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 var admin = require('firebase-admin');
 var promise=require('promise');
 admin.initializeApp();

 exports.sendRequestReceivedNotification=functions
        .database
        .ref('/Requests/{receiverID}/receivedFrom/{senderID}')
        .onCreate((snapshot,context)=>{
            const receiverID= context.params.receiverID;
            const senderID=context.params.senderID;
            console.log(senderID,' sent message to ',receiverID);


            admin.database().ref()
                            .child('DeviceTokens')
                            .child(receiverID)
                            .child('deviceToken')
                            .once('value')
                            .then(function(snapshot){
                                var token=snapshot.val();
                                console.log(token);
                                return true;
                            })
                            .catch(function(error){
                                return false;
                            });

            });
```

while deploying, running and triggering the function i am getting the error as shown in the following snapshot. 
 I have googled abut promises, then().catch() structure but could not get the grasp and the illusion has been never clear to me... :(

return undeifned value:

[image]

Could someone be kind enough to explain the issue here and remedy to this problem please?

Comment: add return before admin.database like return admin.database().ref()

Comment: Thankyou so much.. It worked indeed. Really thankful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your function returns `undefined` is that you never return the value from it. To return the result of your complex computation (with all the promises), add `return` before you start the chain:

```
return admin.database().ref()
       // all other calls
```

Of course you can store the result into a variable, and return it later:

```
const result = admin.database().ref() // and the rest of the chain
// other things you do
return result;
```

Another way to return a value, which is not very useful in this particular case, but could theoretically save you from having this issue, is using a short syntax of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), as you use them anyway:

```
// in case the body of a function can be a single expression,
// it is returned implicitly
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
```

Comment: And is it like the return value from the above function is going to be either true or false? And it seems like i cant create other codes beneath this function.  On trying doing so , I get unreachable code error. does it mean that I have to specify rest of the logic inside then () .. Please dont bother to answer :)

Comment: I added another option that would let you to save the result, do other stuff, and then return it.